# Could not start emulator within 30 seconds

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I'm new to react-native, Android studio(for testing purposes).
What I'm trying to do?

well, I have build an a react native app using `create-react-native` and then I got the app, I've installed Android-studio then, No Issue.

what went wrong?
When I run the app using `yarn android` which is pretty much recommended by them, I got this error

```
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
```

What I've tried so far ...?
I have tried to launch it manually but it doesn't connect to the app.
Launch it manually means:
1- `yarn start`
2- launching the simulator from inside the Android studio